# How to USE Sphinx Search with YII?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, sphinx

My Webapp have full text search..and I found this extension & installed it to my app...

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dgsphinxsearch/

### (DGSphinxSearch Extension)

In main.php I included this,

```
'search' => array(
            'class' => 'application.components.DGSphinxSearch',
            'server' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 9312,
            'maxQueryTime' => 3000,
            'enableProfiling'=>0,
            'enableResultTrace'=>0,
            'fieldWeights' => array(
                'name' => 10000,
                'keywords' => 100,
            ),
),
```

---

Now I have no idea how to use it... can you guys give me an example how to use it?

I want to search Items from description...

```
ITEM TABLE
id
code
description
```

Please help me...

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dgsphinxsearch/#hh4 all clear

Comment: Exactly, did you even try the 'Usage' section on that page...

Comment: ya i tried...but where to select model/table.

Comment: Im getting an error...connection to localhost:9312 failed (errno=10061, msg=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reindex all means:

```
indexer.exe --rotate --config c:\sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf --all
```

and restart "SphinxSearch" service.

Thankx.